# How to set an argparse argument to a value if it's included in the CLI otherwise set it to another value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, argparse

I have an argument that I wish to set to a value if the flag is included in the CLI, otherwise I want it to be set to another. Is there a way to do this with argparse?

The way I do this using `sys.argv` is the following:

```
main("first_val" if "-t" in sys.argv else "second_val")
```

How would I do this with argparse?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `store_true` action if you want a boolean value:

```
p.add_argument('-t', action='store_true')
```

The value of the `t` option will be `True` if its passed on the command line, `None` otherwise.

If you want specific values, you can combine `store_const` and `default`:

```
p.add_argument('-t', action='store_const', const='foo', default='bar')
```

The value of `t` will be `foo` if `-t` was passed on the command line, `bar` otherwise.